# System.Object[] error cannot be converted

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm not sure what's going on any help appreciated.  I'm passing to the code below string and string[3].

```
public void SetSwitch(string name, string[] parameters)
{
  _memberFactory.CallMember(3, "SetSwitch", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string[]) }, new object[] { name, parameters }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

CallMember(int memberCode, string memberName, Type[] parameterTypes, params object[] parms)
    {
     object result = methodInfo.Invoke(GetLateBoundObject, parms);
    }
```

What I'm getting is this error...

{"Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an extra argument -- `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` -- when you call `CallMember`. This means that your `parms` array effectively becomes something like this:

```
new object[] { new object[] { name, parameters }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture }
```

So when you then call `methodInfo.Invoke` you're passing an `object[]` and a `CultureInfo` as arguments when the method is presumably expecting a `string` and a `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an overload method for CallMember?

The reason I ask is that you are passing in five arguments into CallMember, but the CallMember method you show only accepts four arguments.

My guess is that there is an overload method for CallMember, and the object array you are passing in is going in the place for a string argument.